# Showing Google login page in GWT Frame

Tags: javascript, gwt, iframe, callback

I'm developing a GWT application that uses Google login. For this I have a Java servlet that redirects the user to the Google login page based on the UserService.createLogin() function. The Java servlet in question can be accessed at "/login" URL. Previously, whenever users click the login button in the application, I opened a window as follows,

```
Window.open("/login", "Bla", "");
```

Then, when the login procedure is successful (UserService.getCurrentUser() != null) I perform a redirect in the Java servlet as follows,

```
response.sendRedirect("/success.html");
```

The success.html file contains a simple  line where the onLoad() does the following,

```
<body onLoad="window.opener.loginSucceededCallback();window.close();"/>
```

This causes the original window to close and calls a JavaScript callback function 'loginSucceededCallback' which I registered in the GWT class which called the Window.open(). This works fine.

I'm showing the Google login in a separate window because I don't want the GWT application to have to reload. However, it would be much nicer if I could embed the Google login page inside the GWT app instead of showing it in a popup window (or a separate tab). For this, I was considering to use the Frame() or NamedFrame() object which allows display of external pages. I can successfully show the Google login page in such a frame, however when login (at Google) succeeds I cannot get the JavaScript code in success.html to correctly call the callback function in the GWT code. There is no clear 'window' or 'window.opener' object anymore, at least I think. My JavaScript knowledge is also kind of limited and none of the existing forum posts made me see the light...

Does anybody have an idea how to link together these pieces of code such that a successful login on the server side gets noticed by the GWT client? Can I do something with a FormPanel and Frame()?

Thanks,

Ralph

Comment: By using Anchor tag we can connect to Gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
  frame.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
            if(frame.getUrl().equals("your link here"))
                               loginSucceededCallback();
        }
    });
```